# Intersection of Dedekind Domains

Tags: commutative-algebra

If $ A $, $ B $ are subrings of a field $ K $ that are Dedekind domains, is it true that $ A \cap B $ is also a Dedekind domain?

Case in point: $ \mathbb{Z}_{(3) }  ,  \mathbb{Z}_{(5) }  \subset \mathbb{Q} $ and their intersection is again a localizattion (at the complement of $ (3) \cup (5) $) which is a Dedekind domain.

Comment: Essentially, what I need to know is whether $ \dim (A \cap B)  \leq  1 $. In general, subrings can have larger dimension (i.e. subrings in fields).